# Load Data from SQL Server into a combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox

I tried to get data from SQL Server (2 tables: `Famille` and `Compte`) into 2 comboboxes in the `Form_Load()`.

But as you see the result, it works with the 1st combobox, but the 2nd it shows `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader`

[image]

This is the Code

```
private void Tresorerie_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        conn.Open();
        String queryCompte = "select NomCom from Compte";
        String queryFamille = "select NomFam from Famille";
        commCompte = new SqlCommand(queryCompte, conn);
        commFamille = new SqlCommand(queryFamille, conn);

        try
        {
            //Compte
            commCompte.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            dreaderCompte = commCompte.ExecuteReader();

            while (dreaderCompte.Read())
            {
                queryCompte = dreaderCompte[0].ToString();
                TreComBoxCompte.Items.Add(queryCompte);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem with load Compte");
        }
        finally
        {
            dreaderCompte.Close();
        }

        try
        {
            //Famille
            commFamille.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            dreaderFamille = commFamille.ExecuteReader();

            while (dreaderFamille.Read())
            {
                queryFamille = dreaderFamille[0].ToString();
                TreComBoxFamille.Items.Add(dreaderFamille);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem with load Famille");
        }
        finally
        {
            dreaderFamille.Close();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: For second combobox you are adding datareader. TreComBoxFamille.Items.Add(dreaderFamille);

Comment: To me this seems sort of odd to pull back your display text and your value in 2 separate (and seemingly unrelated) queries.  If these values are somehow related, you should likely be doing joins against the tables and pulling in the data all in one shot (this will save on trips back and forth to the database as well).  I know this isn't really answering the question as asked, but unless I'm missing something, this is something you really should look at.

Comment: so how to do that, because I did that to knwo where the problem when the DB can't return data

Comment: I think I misunderstood.  Didn't realize we were looking at two separate drop downs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For second combobox you are adding your datareader **dreaderFamille**:

```
TreComBoxFamille.Items.Add(dreaderFamille);
```

while you should add **queryFamille**:

```
queryFamille = dreaderFamille[0].ToString();
TreComBoxFamille.Items.Add(queryFamille);
```

If you pay attention to item texts in your `ComboBox` you will guess the problem and when you look at code, you will see your guess is true.

Comment: thnx, I don't know how I can't see it :(

Comment: You are welcome :) If you pay attention to item texts in combobox you will guess it and then you will see your guess is true :)

Answer (score 0):

for 2nd comboxbox, you are using wrong object to add

```
TreComBoxFamille.Items.Add(queryFamille);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
while (dreaderFamille.Read())
{
    queryFamille = dreaderFamille[0].ToString();
    TreComBoxFamille.Items.Add(queryFamille);
}
```